# Ajax submit is not happening properly

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Guys this is my first question. I have a table which displays the students name and the input fields to enter their exam marks. The table header shows the subjects(its in a while loop) and has an input field to enter max marks for all of them. This max marks is updated thru Ajax. Its not happening properly. If we press submit first time, nothing will happen. If we press submit second time, it submits. If we press third time, it updates twice, if we press fourth time, it updates thrice (the success message shows thrice)
Code -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#maxmarks<?php echo "$m";?>").validate({

    rules:{

        maxmarks:{

        number: true,

        }

    },
    messages:{

        maxmarks:{

            number: "Please enter a valid marks",

        }

    },
    submitHandler: function(form){

        $("#maxmarks<?php echo "$m";?>").submit(function(){

            $.ajax({

                url : 'components/teacher/performance/maxupdate.php', 
                type : 'POST', 
                data : $("#maxmarks<?php echo "$m";?>").serialize(),
                success : function(res){

                    $('#resultreturn').prepend(res);

                }
            });
            return false;
        }); 

    }                 
 });
 });
 </script>
```

The form has the same id as the script above. Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Side note: This is icky: `<?php echo "$m";?>` use `<?=$m?>`. There is no reason to wrap the variable in a double quotes, and use `<?=` instead of `<?php echo`

Comment: @Ariel beware of that, I've seen quite a bunch of servers with short tags disabled ...

Comment: but still double quotes ain't right...

Comment: @yent "Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available." http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag Even if you disable short tags `<?=` will still work in PHP 5.4.0 and later.

Comment: @Ariel sure but >5.4 systems aren't the rule ... If you just look at the RedHat familly it is already a hassle to upgrade to 5.3 using packages and 5.4 isn't even in the "security" repositories ... Here at work we have mainly RedHat systems and I just recently initiated the idea of moving to 5.3 but sysadmins opposes the idea because of aforementionned reasons ... In fact hosting companies are most of the time up to date as it is a good thing for them to anounce, but other companies often prefer to "keep things as is" if things work, costs less ...

Comment: @yent Well for now 5.3.15 is still supported, but it won't be for much longer (a few months probably). Are you saying Red Hat still has 5.2? Ouch. That's 6 years old at this point, and not supported for almost 2 years.

Comment: @Ariel I know ... The problem is that for some reasons they pushed php 5.3 as a new package named php53, so it is not just a matter of upgrading but replacing a package by another, with all the dependencies problems it implies ... Just yesterday I had to cancel one of those "upgrades" because the package manager insisted on removing a bunch of other packages relying on php because it wasn't able to get that php and php53 are actually the same software ... It sucks big time, but there are alot of other advantages to RedHat (24/7 pro support ...) you don't have with other distros ...

Comment: @yent So call up that support and ask how to install php 5.4 :)

Comment: @Ariel Alas, answer would be "not in the secure tagged repositories so no support for that" :S, the solution would be changing systems, but we got over 1k machines with high security requirements ...

Comment: @yent High security and PHP 5.2 do NOT go together! Is red hat at least backporting all security fixes?

Comment: @Ariel They are, they may have a realllllly long package update cycle their 1st claim is to be secure (they wait a lot for packages to be highly stable, tested, reviewed and proofed before adding them to the secure repositories, that's okay with software that doesn't change much but is not really fit to a quick changing software like php, by quick changing I mean a major release more than every 2 or 3 years ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the submit handler twice. Once as `submitHandler:`, then you do it again as `.submit()`

One or the other - not both.

The first time the form is submitted it creates the submit handler (as you told it to with `.submit()`) but doesn't actually run it.

The second time it runs it (since you created it earlier), and then creates it again. Each time you run it you get more of them.

Comment: Thanks mate! This site really has awesome people!